# how to push value in certain object in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
let arr = [];

let obj {case:''};
```

after I did below code twice,

```
arr.push(obj)
```

I got arr below

```
[{…}, {…}]
0: {case: ''}case: 
1: {case: ''}
length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

and I just want to push certain value (ex. 'a') in first object.

so, I did below code

```
arr[0].case = 'a'
```

but, second object is also changed like below

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {case: 2}
1: {case: 2}
```

So,  I want to know how to push certain value in certain object in an array.

Comment: Please don't directly copy the output from your console into the question, it doesn't format very well. Instead, log the stringified results and copy those to your question. For example `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))`

Comment: Object.values? Is this what you mean?

Comment: FYI you want `arr.push({ ...obj })` to break the object references

Comment: You're adding the *same object* to the array twice. If you modify that object, both references to that object will reflect those modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are stored as references, so to push the object twice and change one of them, you want to push them by:

```js
arr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

If you push your object to your array in this way, you should be able to change one item and not have the other change.